# Mongoid: Changing the order of documents in an embeds_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have a mongoid document which embeds other documents with a relation like
this:

embeds_many :blocks

Creating new blocks works fine, but I cannot manage to change the
order of existing embedded documents. For example I have three
embedded blocks and I want to move the last one to the first
position.What's the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to deal with this with mongoid's recursively_embeds_many feature, but it's essentially the same. There's nothing wrong as far as I can tell with literally rewriting the document. Write a model method to do something like:

```
def reverse_blocks
  reversed_blocks = blocks.to_a.reverse
  blocks.clear
  reversed_blocks.each do |b|
    blocks.create b.attributes
  end
  save
end
```

That's not great code above, but it gives you an idea of how to do what you want to do. I'm not thrilled with having to go through that just to reorder stuff in an array, but there it is.

Comment: This does not seem to work (anymore? - i'm using mongoid 3.0.9). Without duping b.attributes i get an error because of a frozen hash. And then i run into problems with _id/_type not beeing accessible (attr_accessible). So i needed to disable mass assignment protection (which i don't want anyway)

Comment: You might be right.  This was definitely discovered on Mongoid 2.  You're going to want to condition the b.attributes to only be the fields you want to copy, leaving out the _id, _type, etc.  The attributes method must work differently in 3, I can only assume.

Comment: If you want to preserve protected attributes (_id, _type, etc...) you will need to set those explicitly.

example:
`new_block = blocks.build(b.attributes)`
`new_block._id = b._id`
`new_block.save`

Answer (score 1):

I think, that really correct way is make in your embedded docs field "weight" and query them with asc(:weight) or desc(:weight). You don't rely on the order of persisted non-embedded docs, so you shouldn't in embedded.

But if you urgently need to make this, your embedded docs in mongoid are just array, so you can do such way:

```
doc.embedded_docs = [doc.embedded_docs.last] + doc.embedded_docs[0..-2]
```

Comment: I tried that, but the array is empty afterwards!? I see this behaviour also if I try "reverse" or something like that. Using :weight is not an option. I use MongoDB because I don't want to do it the "SQL way". ;-)

Comment: I got feedback from the mongodb list. Moving single array elements is not possible. One has to rewrite the document, but that seems not to be possible with Mongoid and embedded documents. So your solution using a weight/ordering seems to be the best one - even if I don't like it. :-/

Comment: actually MongoDB is not a pure NoSQL solution, but a kind of hybrid of relational and NoSQL approach. So I think, that such method is rather efficient.